# Mix path parameters with query parameters for get request in rest?

Tags: api, rest, routes, query-string

I have a path like this:

```js
 GET http://aaa.com/invoices/{someType}/<bunch of optional query parameters>
```

It is okay to mix path parameters with regular query parameters in rest api?
Or better use required query parameters maybe there is better approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It is okay to mix path parameters with regular query parameters in rest api?

Yes.  REST doesn't care what spelling you use for your resource identifiers -- any spelling that complies with the production rules described by [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#appendix-A) is fine.  Information encoded into the URI is done at the server's discretion and for its own use.

From the perspective of a general purpose client, the identifier is the entire URI.

```
/a/b/c/d
/a/b/c/d?hasOptionalParameter=true
```

As far as REST is concerned, these are two *different* identifiers, and therefore two *different* resources.  That you have a single endpoint for them is an implementation detail.

[URI Templates](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6570) allow you to describe "a range of Uniform Resource Identifiers through variable expansion."  General purpose templates support variable expansion on both path segments and the query part.

But: one of the most familiar URI Templates is an HTML form; the processing rules for `GET` [perform a replacement](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/association-of-controls-and-forms.html#form-submission-algorithm) of the query part of the form action, but leaves unchanged the path segments.  In effect, the path part of the form action URI is protected from change by the client, but the query part gets changed.